# Proving $1+2CZ+3C^2Z^2+....=1/(1-CZ)^2$, considering $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}c^iZ^i=(1-CZ)(1+2CZ+3C^2Z^2+....)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science, recursion

I'm told that we can prove this common identity for solving generating functions: $1+2CZ+3C^2Z^2+....=1/(1-CZ)^2$

Using only the property

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}c^iZ^i=(1-CZ)(1+2CZ+3C^2Z^2+....)$

All I can think of is to move the $(1-CZ)$ to the same side as the summation and try to show the summation is equal to $1/(1-CZ)$, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
(1-CZ)\sum_{k\ge  1} k(CZ)^{k-1}
&= \sum_{k\ge  1} k(CZ)^{k-1} - \sum_{k\ge  1} k(CZ)^{k}
\\&= \sum_{k\ge  1} k(CZ)^{k-1} - \sum_{k\ge  2} (k-1)(CZ)^{k-1}
\\&= 1  + \sum_{k\ge  2} (CZ)^{k-1} 
\\&= \sum_{k\ge  0} (CZ)^{k} = \\
(1-CZ)^2\sum_{k\ge  1} k(CZ)^{k-1} &= (1-CZ)\sum_{k\ge  0} (CZ)^{k} 
\\ &= \sum_{k\ge  0} (CZ)^{k} - \sum_{k\ge  0} (CZ)^{k+1} = 1
\end{align}
using nothing but elementary sum manipulations.